# how to add a react widget to a 3rd-party site

Tags: javascript, reactjs, widget

I'm trying to develop a widget that will be integrated into other sites using Next.js (http://splashup-demo.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/quiz), it works fine as a standalone app, but I don't have a clue how to embed it into external sites.
Any links to resources regarding this topic or any pieces of advice would be useful.

Comment: I would create an npm package out of it. https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/04/14/react-npm-how-to-publish-a-react-component-to-npm

Comment: And what about script tag implementation? https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#add-react-in-one-minute
Is it useful?